# Decode ob_start() data

Tags: php, ob-start

This is definitely a newbie question, since I'm not sure where to start on this.

I've used a PHP anti-spam form email script for years which was purchased from a developer (who has ceased their business) but is sometimes flagged as suspicious by our web host. It continues to work flawlessly, but I'd like to understand more what it's doing...

Is there a way to decode what is wrapped into the following:

```
<?php ob_start();?>FJ3HbutclkZfpYfV4IA5oRr1gznnzEmBOY....?>
```

The code, of course, is much longer than the above.

Your ideas, suggestions are most appreciated.

Dan

Comment: This looks like it might have been encoded with IonCube Encoder. Do you have that (or anything similar) installed on your server?

Comment: Hi Alex, I don't think so, no!

Comment: Run `php -i` from the command line or hit a page that calls `phpinfo()` and it will print all the installed modules.

Comment: So what is the rest of the code? `ob_start` captures the following line into a string variable. And how is it used then?

Comment: [deleted] Oops zerkms, misread your comment, I thought you were posing the Q to me specifically.

Comment: Alex, good catch. I see this: Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.5.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies

Comment: @zerkms The full code is here: http://pastebin.com/XA9p4Mwp

Comment: `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode($c)))` heh heh

Comment: Heh this is wacky. Is this how IonCube normally works? The decoded and inflated code is more encoded and deflated code.

Comment: Oh man, there are 35 layered calls to evaled deflated decoded hunks.

Comment: I don't believe this is IonCube encoded, it looks to be an amateurish attempt at obfuscation.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NxrczXww

Comment: How did you extract that Alex? I tried the eval(gzinflate(base64_decode($c))) you suggested and got more gobblygook.

Comment: You have to do it 35 times. :)

Comment: Wow, that is amateurish but succeeded in the sense of keeping most of the prying eyes out!...am trying to mark your reply as answered...don't see a choice to do that.

Comment: I'll post it as an actual reply instead of a comment, you can tag that.

Comment: PS is there an easy way to this extraction on the command line in Linux, for example?

Comment: I just changed the `eval` calls to `echo`, then saved the output to a new file, and repeated until I got the code. Had I know it was going to take 35 iterations, I probably would have scripted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a messily obfuscated hunk of open source classes, including PHPMailer. Full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/NxrczXww). Note this looks pretty old and will not work as-is with PHP versions greater than 5.6.

Comment: Thanks Alex, this was educational to say the least!

Comment: Warning -- this code appears to be vulnerable to SQL injections. You probably want to switch to something more up-to-date.

Comment: Will do! Thanks again.